# Angular apply class in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, dom-manipulation, angularjs-ng-class

I have a angular directive which will produce bootstrap form-group, looks for $scope.errors for value of ng-model of the directive to show errors.. Example below:
My html code:

```
<input type="text" b-input ng-model="data.company.name" label="Company Name" class="form-control"/>
```

and my directive code:

```
app.directive('bInput', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        replace: true,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var div = $('<div>', {
                'class': 'form-group',
                'ng-class': " 'has-error' : errors." + attrs.ngModel + " != null "
            });

            $compile(div)(scope);
            element.wrap(div);
            if (attrs.label != undefined) {
                element.before('<label for="' + attrs.name + '" class="control-label">' + attrs.label + '</label>');
                element.removeAttr('label');
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Can you please explain me how do i achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify element inside the compile fn of the directive because at DOM is plain. and then recompile that element inside the link function which is return from compile function.

**Code**

```
app.directive('bInput', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    replace: true,
    compile: function(element, attrs) {
      var div = $('<div>', {
        'class': 'form-control',
        'ng-class': " 'has-error' : errors." + attrs.ngModel + " != null "
      });
      element.wrap(div);
      if (attrs.label != undefined) {
        element.before('<label for="' + attrs.name + '" class="control-label">' + attrs.label + '</label>');
        element.removeAttr('label');
      }
      element.removeAttr('b-input');
      return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var linkFn = $compile(element);
        linkFn(scope)
      }
    };
  });
```

Look at similar [**SO answer here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31062143/2435473)

Comment: @Pankaj-Parker No but it adds 'ng-valid' 
output:
<div class="form-group ng-valid" ng-class="{'has-error' : errors.company.name != null}">

Comment: @DesterDezzods try updated..also refer the link answer which is already answered by me only..Thanks :)

Comment: @DesterDezzods Glad to help you..Also do read the linked answer..would help you more.. Thanks :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83675/discussion-between-pankaj-parkar-and-dester-dezzods).