# how to add ng-change handler dynamically to input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```js
app.directive('textForm', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: "textForm.html",
        scope: {
            label: "@",
            model: "=",
            type: "@",
            name: "@",
        },
        link: function (scope, element) {
            scope.log = function () {
                console.log(1);
            };

            var input = element.find('.form-control');
            input.attr({'ng-change': 'log()'});
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<!-- this is textForm.html -->
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-xs-3 control-label">{{label}}</label>
    <div class="col-xs-7">
        <input type="{{type||'text'}}" name="{{name}}" class="form-control" ng-model="model">
    </div>
</div>

<!-- this is how I use the directive -->
<text-form label="name" name="name" model="person.name"></text-form>
```

the above code couldn't run, but can tell the problem.

I want to add `ng-change` to `input` dynamically for some reason and after some search I found `$compile` could do this. But it seems doesn't work and I don't know why.

My angular version is 1.5.5

Comment: Where are you referring your `directive` in your HTML?

Comment: What is the use case for doing that?

Comment: @troy what you gonna add in `ng-change` dynamically & based on what??

Comment: @georgeawg actually I want to add ng-pattern, ng-max, ng-min, etc for input validation, but some input need these and some doesn't. And to make this directive more customizable, I need to add some attribute dynamically. ng-change was just an example

Comment: @PankajParkar I've explained above

Comment: @troy look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31502481/2435473), there I'm adding dynamic attributes to DOM..

Comment: @troy I hope this has solved your issue, So marked as duplicate :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are compiling the `text-form` element (given by the directive), but you append the ng-change attribute to the `.form-control` element (which is not even a child of your directive). So angular is not aware of this and does not integrate the ng-change properly.

I think you should use this directive on the element you want to control this way, i.e.:

```
<input text-form type="{{type||'text'}}" name="{{name}}" class="form-control" ng-model="model">
```

and make the directive restrict to 'A' or 'AE'

Not sure, but I think it would also work if your directive is placed on a parent (e.g. the form element).

Comment: makes sence, but I am trying to make a bootstrap inline form, so I can't change the dom structure

Comment: hmm... but you're not changing the dom structure, you just need to place the directive on the right element when you invoke compile

Comment: something like `$compile(input)(scope);` ? it doesn't work. I solved my problem using Pankaj Parkar's method