# How can I have a ngChange on a table?

Tags: angularjs

My problem is the following. I have a table with several rows. I want to validate some input. I will try to explain how my table looks like:

> table  
>   ----  tbody 
>   ---- ----      tr  
>   ---- ---- ----        td select1  
>   ---- ---- ----        td select2  
>     ---- ---- ----       td select3  
>   ---- ----   tr   
>   ---- ---- ----        td select1
>   
>    ---- ---- ----       td select2  
>     ---- ---- ----      td
>   select3

I want that when one of the selects is changed to call the same function of validation. I don't want to put a ngChange on all the selects. I want to have one ngChange on table so that whenever a select is modified, no matter which one, the same function will be called.\

As far as I knew, the table already knows when one of its rows is modified, but I wanted to know if there is any angularjs way of doing this.

Comment: The "AngularJS way" is to put `ng-change` on the select elements. The way you mention is the "jQuery way" (something like `$("table select").on(...)`). The middle option is to create a directive for your table (like in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42479662/how-to-add-ng-change-handler-dynamically-to-input)

Comment: That is a good suggestion, using a directive. Thank you.