# Angular $compile in link function gives an error "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to add a ng-class attribute to a custom directive from the link function. But when using compile function after adding the ng-class attribute, It throws an error like "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Please see the code below

```
MyApp.directive('twinField',function($compile){
return {
    restrict:'A',
    require:'ngModel',
    scope:{
        fval:'='
    },
    link:function(scope,ele,attr,ctrl){
        ctrl.$validators.compareTo=function(val){
            //alert(scope.fval)
            return scope.fval==val
        }
        scope.$watch('fval', function(newValue, oldValue, scope) {
            ctrl.$validate()
        });
        ele.attr("ng-class","addForm.cpassword.$error.compareTo?'errorpswd':''")//=""
        $compile(ele)(scope);
    }
}
```

})

It is working when I add the ng-class directly in the html.

Comment: can you provide a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: I guess, you shouldn't be using compile function in the link function, instead use link function in compile function. Also, compile function is called only one time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$compile(ele)(scope);` line in compiling directive element, which will leads to call compile your directive code in infinite loop, that's why it is giving  `“RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded”` error.

Ideally you should use combination of compile and link function together. From compile function you need to add `ng-class` attribute & then remove the directive attribute to avoid directive element to compile indefinitely. Then compile your directive element with scope from directive link function.

**Code**

```
myApp.directive('twinField', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    scope: {
      fval: '='
    },
    compile: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
      console.log(tElement)

      tElement.removeAttr('twin-field');

      return function(scope, ele, attr, ctrl) {
        ele.attr("ng-class", "addForm.cpassword.$error.compareTo?'errorpswd':''");
        ele.attr("test", "{{test}}':''");
        var compileFn = $compile(ele);
        ctrl.$validators.compareTo = function(val) {
          //alert(scope.fval)
          return scope.fval == val
        }
        scope.$watch('fval', function(newValue, oldValue, scope) {
          ctrl.$validate()
        });
        compileFn(scope);
      }
    }
  }
})
```

[**Similar answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31061732/angularjs-custom-form-validation-directive-doesnt-work-in-my-modal/31062143#31062143)

[Demo here](http://plnkr.co/edit/5DWS9ya8IZzqaLyykHhf?p=preview)

But the other thing, I don't see any advantage with your code of adding and removing class using `ng-class` directive. As you are setting validity of your form control, implicitly you are adding and removing `ng-valid-compare-to`(on valid) & `ng-invalid-compare-to`(on invalid) class. So there is no need to create extra overhead to have `ng-class` logic to putting same thing again.

Comment: Actually i am adding ng-class attribute in the same tag which i added the custom drective. Compiling only inner elements dont resolve the ng-class attribute added in the custom directive tag right?

Comment: @Nijeesh I got what you are saying, I updated my answer.thanks :)

Comment: @Nijeesh did you get to time to look at the updated & linked answer,

Comment: Thanks @Pankaj Parker.The error is solved using your answer.I had to add a small change in your answer. `tElement.removeAttr('twinField'); - tElement.removeAttr('twin-field');`. But the added ng-class still not working.And it working when i added it to the html.

Comment: @Nijeesh did you look at reference answer..which has same thing..added `ng-class` from the directive

Comment: Yes, I used the same, but the ng-class is not working

Comment: Prker Thank you very much, I changed it to use the class name ng-invalid-compare-to.Thank you very much for your effort

Comment: Glad to help you..Thanks :)

Comment: removing the directive saved me. thats what caused the infinite loop