# angular, compile attribute added via directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ecmascript-6

Using ES6 and webpack in my angular project, and trying how to compile a dynamically added angular material directive to my input.

My Directive looks like this

```
    class addMaxLength {
    constructor() {
        this.restrict = 'A';
        this.scope = {
            maxLength : '='
        };

    }

    // optional link function
    link(scope, element, attributes) {
        if(scope.maxLength > 0){
            element.attr('md-maxlength',scope.maxLength);
        }
    }
}

addMaxLength.$inject = [];

export { addMaxLength };
```

And trying to see how I can compile the input then to show the new attribute on my input ?

Comment: Can you please go through [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34805598/2435473)?

Comment: Creating a class instead of an object is overhead and has absolutely no value. It's even called directive definition **object**.