# Adding ng-pattern dyanmically through a directive isn't kicking off validation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-pattern

I'm attempting to add ng-pattern to specific inputs on specific forms using the following directive.  It's adding the ng-pattern, but the validation isn't working.  However, the validation works fine whenever I add the ng-pattern manually to the inputs.  My only assumption as to why this isn't working is that angular isn't recognizing the ng-pattern being added to the input fields?  If that's the case, how can this be resolved?  Sorry, I'm kind of an Angular noob.  Here's my directive:

```
.directive('billValidation', [() => {
       return {
           restrict: 'A',
           link:(scope, element, attrs) => {
               $(element).find('.validate-bill-input').each(function() {
                   $(this).attr('ng-Pattern', '/^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$/');
               });
           }
    } 
}])
```

Comment: You could refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31062143/2435473)

Comment: You can simply add ng-pattern="pattern" and change pattern