# Binding dynamically generated angular directive text on an element

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to make a directive that when applied to any input element adds a data-ng-pattern. now i want to bind it. I looked around and found something but its not working.

```
mainModule.directive("telephoneValidation", function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        replace: true,
        link:
            function (scope, element, attrs) {
                element.attr('data-ng-pattern','^[\( ]{0,1}[\+ ]{0,1}[0-9 ]+[\)]{0,1}[0-9\- ]*$/');
                $compile(element.contents())(scope);
                element.removeAttr('telephone-validation').empty();
            }
    };
});
```

Comment: What do you want to archive with this: $compile(element.contents())(scope);?

Comment: Basically inside compile phase you have to add `ng-pattern` attribute & remove directive attribute. Thereafter compile element from link again. Take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31062143/2435473) would help you.

Comment: @eg16 i am trying to recompile the DOM element to achieve 2 way binding on the element so that angular watches the element and responds accordingly. Currently is is acting as a custom attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$compile(element)(scope)` instead.  Using `contents()` targets the element's children, not the element itself - https://api.jquery.com/contents/

Comment: yes. .contents() does not work and this does. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my stupidity. I had written the value of the attribute incorrectly it was missing a forward slash in the beginning. The element is getting compiled dynamically with the same code.

A way to be more sure is to wrap the element as an angular element by using

```
angular.element(element)
```

and then passing it to compile

```
compile(angular.element(element))(scope));
```

I found the solution reading the compile documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler)